# H2O reduce free memory each prediction - result OOM

Tags: python-3.x, memory, h2o

I build application with h2o. Each call to my application do prediction on H2O.
H2O instant is starting with application, then each call is connecting to this instant.

My problem is that with a time my free memory counter is decreasing.

This is my logs during connecting to existed H2O instance.

```
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 --------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 Python version:             3.6.4 final
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O API Extensions:         Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O internal security:      False
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O connection proxy:
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O connection url:         http://localhost:54321
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster status:         locked, healthy
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster allowed cores:  2
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster total cores:    2
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster free memory:    5.903 Gb
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster total nodes:    1
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster name:           H2O_from_python_cdsw_dwwqwt
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster version age:    1 year and 7 days !!!
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster version:        3.24.0.1
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster timezone:       Europe/Zurich
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 H2O cluster uptime:         39 mins 45 secs
2020-04-08 12:11:23.821 --------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------
```

```
2020-04-08 12:11:46.578 --------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------
2020-04-08 12:11:46.578 Python version:             3.6.4 final
2020-04-08 12:11:46.578 H2O API Extensions:         Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
2020-04-08 12:11:46.578 H2O internal security:      False
2020-04-08 12:11:46.578 H2O connection proxy:
2020-04-08 12:11:46.578 H2O connection url:         http://localhost:54321
2020-04-08 12:11:46.578 H2O cluster status:         locked, healthy
2020-04-08 12:11:46.578 H2O cluster allowed cores:  2
2020-04-08 12:11:46.578 H2O cluster total cores:    2
2020-04-08 12:11:46.577 H2O cluster free memory:    5.890 Gb
2020-04-08 12:11:46.577 H2O cluster total nodes:    1
2020-04-08 12:11:46.577 H2O cluster name:           H2O_from_python_cdsw_v1eq0y
2020-04-08 12:11:46.577 H2O cluster version age:    1 year and 7 days !!!
2020-04-08 12:11:46.577 H2O cluster version:        3.24.0.1
2020-04-08 12:11:46.577 H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
2020-04-08 12:11:46.577 H2O cluster timezone:       Europe/Zurich
2020-04-08 12:11:46.577 H2O cluster uptime:         40 mins 8 secs
2020-04-08 12:11:46.577 --------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------
```

It works until it has memory and then it stopped working (because of OOM). How can I handle with this case? Can I removing something in schedule (old logs) to keep the level of free memory constant?

Comment: You aren't showing any code here.  But if you want to remove datasets from memory you can find them with the h2o.ls() and remove them with the h2o.rm() functions from R/python.